# Each bounded measurable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is almost a Borel function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The exact problem statement is:

There exists a Borel function $h:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and a Borel set $H\subset[a,b]$ such that $f=h$ on $H$ and $m([a,b]\setminus H)=0$.

My attempt of the proof is as follows:

We know that every bounded measurable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is nearly continuous, and so let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and choose $\varepsilon_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Moreover, there exists continuous functions $g_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $|g_n|\leq f$ on $[a,b]$ and a closed set $C_n\subset[a,b]$ such that $f=g_n$ on $C_n$ and $m([a,b]\setminus C_n)<\frac{1}{2^n}$. Now, for each $n$, by countable subadditivity of $m$ 
$$m\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty [a,b]\setminus C_k\right)\leq\sum_{k=n}^\infty m([a,b]\setminus C_k)<\infty.$$ Since $f$ is bounded, there exists an $M>0$ such that $|g_n|\leq f\leq M$, which means that $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a uniformly bounded sequence. Now, let $H=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty C_k$. Note that since each $C_k$ is closed and the collection of Borel sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra, it will be closed under countable unions and intersections and hence $H$ is a Borel set. Then we have,

$$m([a,b]\setminus H)=m\left([a,b]\setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty C_k\right)=m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left([a,b]\setminus\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty C_k\right)\right)=m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty[a,b]\setminus C_k\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}m\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty[a,b]\setminus C_k\right)\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty m([a,b]\setminus C_k)=0$$

Now, define $h=\lim\sup g_n$ on $H$. Since $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly bounded, it can shown that $h$ is a Borel function. Since $f=g_n$ on $H$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h$ is defined in terms of $g$, $h$ too agrees with $f$ on $H$.

Everything feels right, except for the last bit about $h$ agreeing with $f$ on $H$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is $g$?${}{}{}$

Comment: There's a statement which says that any bounded measurable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is nearly continuous. And so for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $g$ which is continuous and agrees with $f$ on some closed set $C\subset[a,b]$, $m([a,b]\setminus C)<\varepsilon$ and that $|g|\leq f$. Since I've assumed already that $f$ is a bounded measurable function with domain $[a,b]$, I just applied that result.

Comment: You got $g_n$'s with the aid of that theorem. What is $g$ then?

Comment: There were a series a problems which lead to this one. In those problems, we were given an arbitrary sequence of functions $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $g_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and they were assumed to be uniformly bounded. In those problems, we defined $h$ (as in the above proof) in terms of $g_n's$ and were able to show that $h$ was a Borel function. I'm thinking of editing the problem to include the problems preceding. Would it be helpful to do that?

Comment: @Norbert I totally misunderstood your earlier question. I made a typo writing $g$ instead of $g_n$. I went ahead and updated the question. Hope this clarifies things.